# Switch order of specific list items?

Tags: css

Is there a way to switch the display order of specific list items? For example, with the following list, can the order of the second and third items be switched when displayed?

The list:

```
 <ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
 </ul>
```

How I want it displayed:

- A
- C
- B

Comment: only with css ? (see tag)

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: You can easily change the *display* order of the elements with CSS, but not the HTML order. Do you just want to change the display order?

Comment: Its on wordpress plugin that's why.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox items can be [displayed in an arbitrary order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) by using the `order` property:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think OP wants css only answer.

Comment: The ugly css solution won't work if the text is too long. I think css only support for 1 height. But js solution can solve everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by using below 2 steps:

1. `ul {display : flex; flex-direction: column;}` this will make list in column.
2. As you want to change order of only second child you can use
   `li:nth-child(2) { order: 2;}` this will change order of `B` to third and `C` to second.

Note: Second Element of `li` which is `B` will render at last as we have not assigned order to it.

Thanks...

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```